# Display block com Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Olá,

Não sei mecher muito com javascript e precisava de ajuda, gostaria de fazer um menu que quando clicado mudasse o display de uma div de display:none para display:block.

Meu menu

```
            <div id="back">
                <ul>
                    <li class="li1"><a href="#">O que é?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Objetivo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pré-requisitos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Público-alvo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Metodologia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Conteúdo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Professores</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

teste

Comment: Cara, nao entendi muito bem o q vc quer mas criei um exemplo bem simples de fazer usando jquery. Abs http://jsfiddle.net/claudioromano13/h1c1rkcd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimente o seguinte Javascript:

```
<script>
function exibeDiv(){
var div = document.getElementById("back");
div.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div id='back' onclick='exibeDiv()'>
</div>
```